# How to select and merge objects data with jq?

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

After some hours playing with jq, I need your help for selecting and merging objects.

I have this kind of JSON :

```
{
    "cluster-1": {
        "vhosts": {
            "vhost_aaa": {
                "postgresql": {
                    "bdd1": {
                        "db_aaa": {
                            "user_aaa": {
                                "password": "xxx"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "bdd2": {
                        "db_aaa": {
                            "user_aaa": {
                                "password": "xxx"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "cluster-2": {
        "vhosts": {
            "vhost_bbb": {
                "postgresql": {
                    "bdd1": {
                        "db_bbb": {
                            "user_bbb": {
                                "password": "xxx"
                            },
                            "user_bbb_ro": {
                                "password": "xxx"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "vhost_ccc": {
                "postgresql": {
                    "bdd1": {
                        "db_ccc": {
                            "user_ccc": {
                                "password": "xxx"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a deep JSON which tell me that, on *cluster-x* there is vhosts (*vhosts_xxx*) which may use a kind of database (here *postgresql*) which is hosted by a server (here *bdd1* or *bdd2*) which contains databases (*db_xxx*) where i want to create specified users (*user_xxx*)  with credentials details. Ouf !

My goal is to select part of data to make specific actions, so for databases servers, I want all actions to do on the same server so this is what I try to generate with jq :

```
"bdd1": {
    "db_aaa": {
        "user_aaa": {
            "password": "xxx"
        }
    },
    "db_bbb": {
        "user_bbb": {
            "password": "xxx"
        },
        "user_bbb_ro": {
            "password": "xxx"
        }
    },
    "db_ccc": {
        "user_ccc": {
            "password": "xxx"
        }
    }
},
"bdd2": {
    "db_aaa": {
        "user_aaa": {
            "password": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

With this filter `(..|.vhosts?|..|.postgresql?)|objects`, I can isolate data I need.

```
{
  "bdd1": {
    "db_aaa": {
      "user_aaa": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "bdd2": {
    "db_aaa": {
      "user_aaa": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "bdd1": {
    "db_bbb": {
      "user_bbb": {
        "password": "xxx"
      },
      "user_bbb_ro": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "bdd1": {
    "db_ccc": {
      "user_ccc": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next step is to merge all of theses data grouped by *bddx*.
Any help or advice will be welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` to convert an object to an array of key/value pairs of properties/values.  You could then group those pairs to construct your result.

```
[..|.vhosts?|..|.postgresql?|objects|to_entries[]]
    | reduce group_by(.key)[] as $g ({};
        .[$g[0].key] = [$g[].value]
    )
```

This yields the following result:

```
{
  "bdd1": [
    {
      "db_aaa": {
        "user_aaa": { "password": "xxx" }
      }
    },
    {
      "db_ccc": {
        "user_ccc": { "password": "xxx" }
      }
    },
    {
      "db_bbb": {
        "user_bbb": { "password": "xxx" },
        "user_bbb_ro": { "password": "xxx" }
      }
    }
  ],
  "bdd2": [
    {
      "db_aaa": {
        "user_aaa": { "password": "xxx" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! This will help me a lot for my project and for understand jq in a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be safer (i.e. more robust) to avoid using `..`.  If the data is structured as you have indicated, then the following filter would be appropriate to perform the "select" part of your task:

```
to_entries[] | .value.vhosts
| to_entries[] | .value.postgresql // empty
```

You could then use this along the lines Jeff suggested:

`[to_entries[] | .value.vhosts
 | to_entries[] | .value.postgresql // empty
 | to_entries[]]
| group_by(.key)
| reduce .[] as $g ({}; .[$g[0].key] = [$g[].value] )`

Comment: Thank you for your version that I will use. Safer & better, I love !

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce)s [Sylvain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782760/sylvain)'s filter using [* object multiplication](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Multiplication,division,modulo:*,/,and%)

```
reduce ((..|.vhosts?|..|.postgresql?)|objects) as $i({}; . *= $i)
```

with the sample data it produces

```
{
  "bdd1": {
    "db_aaa": {
      "user_aaa": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "db_bbb": {
      "user_bbb": {
        "password": "xxx"
      },
      "user_bbb_ro": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "db_ccc": {
      "user_ccc": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "bdd2": {
    "db_aaa": {
      "user_aaa": {
        "password": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```